# Execute code in Selenium without using driver

Tags: selenium

I need to execute - `$('input').is('[readonly]')` in my Selenium C# code without using driver.
Can anybody help me with this?
Thanks

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  add some description and explanation and code snippet tried by you. Are you thinking someone understand easily what you have written ?

Comment: this is a JQuery code and not a JavaScript, so I don't think you can execute. Convert this to JavaScript and then use JavaScriptExecutor to execute it.